# Actions must be plain objects using Async Function for signout

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Current code is not returning dispatch response

```
export const signOut = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("userToken");
      dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log();
    }
  };
};
```

Main wallet Page for calling the action

[Wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G23Yo.png)

[image]

Returns nothing tried to add a callback response and I get nothing back...

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make my signout button remove the token from the asyncStorage and send back a dispatch with the type: "LOGOUT" in order to make my usertoken and username null on the reducer switch case. If you need anymore clarification let me know. 
@slideshowp2